# How to handle multiple users in In-App Billing Library ? (Best Practice)

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I am implementing Google's In-App Billing Library in my application and would like to know the best way to handle the following cases

1. Multiple Device and Single User

> Use Case:
>
> - User U1 with Google Play Store Account G1 subscribes to Subscription S1.
> - Now User U1 log out from the app and User U2 login the app.
>
> Queries:
>
> - What will happen if User U2 tries to subscribe the Subscription S1?
> - Shall we restrict the User U2 by saying "This Subscription has already been subscribed to some other user from this Google Account"?

2. Single Device and Multiple User

> Use Case I:
>
> - User U1 with Google Play Store Account G1 subscribes to Subscription S1.
> - User U1 with Google Play Store Account G2 tries to subscribe Subscription S1.
>
> Queries:
>
> - Shall we restrict the User U1 by saying "You have already subscribed to this subscription by some other Google Account"?

> Use Case II
>
> - User U1 with Google Play Store Account G1 subscribes to Subscription S1.
> - User U1 with Google Play Store Account G2 tries to subscribe Subscription S2.
>
> Queries:
>
> - Shall we allow the user to subscribe to different subscriptions with different Google Account?

General Queries:

> - Shall we map each user with a different Google Account and if the user tries to purchase with some other Google Account, restrict it OR
>   ask him to delink his existing linked Google Account first?
> - Can we subscribe(purchase) a subscription from 2 users using the same Google Play Account? (Say using different `accountId` https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setobfuscatedaccountid)

I am expecting a response to my queries in terms of best practices and facts.

Comment: Did you found your answers? I'm also facing the same issue. I've mutiple auth accounts with subscription functionality.

Comment: Any fixes for different app user to allow subscribing the same product on same device using same google play account?

Comment: Same issues here with both Play Store and App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Both the purchase of in-app products and subscriptions are strictly linked to the Google account with which they were made.

You cannot know from a Google account the purchases made by another account, it would be a serious security problem if possible.

If two users (two google accounts) want to use the same subscription, both have to buy it separately.

Answer (score 0):

To answer one of your questions:

- Can we subscribe(purchase) a subscription from 2 users using the same Google Play Account? (Say using different accountId)

Just tried it, and the answer is no.
The setting and reading of our custom `accountId` allows us to know when to show/hide the "subscribe" button.
But, when we log in with the other app user and press "subscribe", Google says:

```
- Error - You're already subscribed to ...
```

Also tried with adding `profileId` - same result.